Does it make sense to include both age and birth year as covariates in a model?
A researcher asked me about adjusting for both age and birth year in a model. To my mind these are perfectly collinear, but then it got me started looking around online and down the rabbit hole of age-period-cohort models (which I still don't really understand).
I'm after some practical advice on whether it ever makes sense to include both of these as covariates in a model, and if so, how and why does it get around the collinearity issue.
If I understand things at a very fundamental level, the problem is that in traditional modelling, correcting for age 'effects' by just including age as a covariate might not actually capture the true age effect as this can also be confounded by when a person was born (cohort) and when data was collected (period). So ideally one would also want to correct for these other effects (but then there is an identification problem). Is that right?
Do these issues equally apply to cross-sectional as well as longitudinal observational data?

Was all data collected at the same time for the model? Age and Birth Year would only be collinear if the data is restricted to having been collected at a specific time. For example, height distributions as a function of age change as a function of time period for which the data were collected (30-year-old people were on average shorter 100 years ago).

Thanks - so that clears up one misunderstanding I had. In cross-sectional data there can be no period effect, because the period is the same for everyone. Then there's not much difference really in whether you use age OR year of birth (but not both) - they are both getting at the same thing. So these ideas really only apply to longitudinal data then...
